# Fix Bootstrap tbody scroll with parent

Tags: html, css

I've created a codepen with fixed table header but there is an issue. When table columns are increased the it shows vertical scroll after scrolling to right side.

How it tbody vertical scroll can be fixed to the parent so it is always visible.

https://codepen.io/cybentizen/pen/eXBaor

```
@media (max-width:991px) {
  table.table-sticky tbody {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  table.table-sticky th,
  table.table-sticky td {
    min-width: 100px !important;
    width: 100px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
table.table-sticky tr {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
table.table-sticky th,
table.table-sticky td {
    min-width: 150px !important;
}

table.table-sticky tbody {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
}
table.table-sticky tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-table;
  float: left;}
  table.table-sticky th {
  padding-left: 0;
}

table.table-sticky {
height: 190px;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

table.table-sticky thead {
position: sticky;
width: calc(100% - 17px) !important;
}

table.table-sticky thead th:last-of-type {
border-right: 0;
}

table.table-sticky tbody {
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
display: inline-block;
height: 150px;
width: 100%;
/* position: absolute; */
}

table.table-sticky-double tbody {
height: 142px;
}

table.table-sticky tr.collapse {
background-color: #eee;
display:none;
}

table.table-sticky tr.collapse.in {
background-color: #eee;
display: table;
}

table.table-sticky tr.collapse.in td {
border:0;
color: #666;
font-size: 11px;
padding: 0px;
}

table.table-sticky tr.collapse.in td input {
border: 0;
background: transparent;
box-shadow: none;
color: #666;
font-size: 11px;
}

table.table-sticky tr.collapsing {
-webkit-transition: none;
transition: none;
display: none;
}
```

I've also added responsive queries in it and styling for TD and TR.

Comment: you can hide the scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used simple trick for your problem. check and try this

```js
function myf(){     
   var el = document.getElementById('mybody');
   document.getElementById('myhead').scrollLeft=el.scrollLeft;
}
```

```css
th, td{
   width:80px;
   text-align:left;
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
    table.table-sticky tbody {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    table.table-sticky th,
    table.table-sticky td {
        min-width: 100px !important;
        width: 100px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    table.table-sticky tr {
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    table.table-sticky th,
    table.table-sticky td {
        min-width: 150px !important;
    }

    table.table-sticky tbody {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}

table.table-sticky tr {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-table;
    float: left;
}

table.table-sticky th {
    padding-left: 0;
}

table.table-sticky {
    height: 190px;
    position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

table.table-sticky thead {
    
}

table.table-sticky thead th:last-of-type {
    border-right: 0;
}

table.table-sticky tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    /* position: absolute; */
}

/*.table-responsive {
    overflow-x: inherit;
}*/

table.table-sticky-double tbody {
    height: 142px;
}

table.table-sticky tr.collapse {
    background-color: #eee;
    display:none;
}

table.table-sticky tr.collapse.in {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: table;
}

table.table-sticky tr.collapse.in td {
    border:0;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 0px;
}

table.table-sticky tr.collapse.in td input {
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 11px;
}

table.table-sticky tr.collapsing {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    display: none;
}

thead{   
    width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 600px;">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sticky">
      <thead id="myhead">
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">Serial</th>
          <th style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">Item code</th>
          <th style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">Item name</th>
          <th style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">Mfg. Date</th>
          <th style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">Expiry Date</th>
          <th style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">Length</th>
          <th style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">Width</th>
          <th style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">Height</th>
          <th style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody onscroll="myf()" id="mybody">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">00010001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">Item 1</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">01/01/2019</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">01/01/2020</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">5.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">3.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">00010001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">Item 1</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">01/01/2019</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">01/01/2020</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">5.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">3.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">00010001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">Item 1</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">01/01/2019</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">01/01/2020</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">5.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">3.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">00010001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">Item 1</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">01/01/2019</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">01/01/2020</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">5.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">3.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">00010001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">Item 1</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">01/01/2019</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">01/01/2020</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">5.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">3.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">00010001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">Item 1</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">01/01/2019</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">01/01/2020</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">5.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">3.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">00010001</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">Item 1</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">01/01/2019</td>
          <td style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">01/01/2020</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">5.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">3.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">0.0</td>
          <td style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">x</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Code Pen Example 1](https://codepen.io/udarakasun/pen/MxJYZK)

[Code Pen Example 2](https://codepen.io/udarakasun/pen/bZgGOM?editors=1000)

Comment: Thanks man!
This solution works like a charm but when I use bootstrap columns then it isn't working.

Comment: I've added bootstrap column class in the code. but currently width is fixed like you've earlier fixed it.
https://codepen.io/cybentizen/pen/eXgNwr

Comment: ill check that, plz give me a few minutes